# Bootstrap hamburger menu not applying background when clicked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a white background when the hamburger menu is pressed when the viewport of the page is in Tablet or Mobile view.

What I'm trying to achieve aesthetically is when the hamburger menu is pressed, change the color of the Logo, Title, Nav-links, and the Menu button to Black and give it all a White background instead of what it currently has, see-through/translucent.

The only time I like everything in the Navbar to be white is in Desktop view.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

```css
/* 

 green: #009688
 brown: #674A48
 off-white: #f8f9fa - text
 black: #212529;


 baby blue: #53B4EB - For winter tabs
 orange: #FF9900 - For summer/fall tabs
 yellow: #FFC700 - For summer tabs

*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7;
    letter-spacing: .25px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*************************
HERO / LANDING PAGE SECTION
**************************/

/* Use psuedo class to apply filter onto image otherwise the brightness filter will also apply to text */
.hero::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: url("/img/hero/hero-zion.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    filter: brightness(90%);
}

.hero-content {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
}

.hero-content .hero-title {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-bottom: .3em;
    line-height: 77px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 5px rgb(29 37 45 / 65%);
}

.hero-content .hero-desc {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    width: 52ch;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 5px rgb(29 37 45 / 100%);
}

.hero-content .hero-button {
    background-color: #009688;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 2px 20px;
    color: #f8f9fa;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 255px;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 5px rgb(29 37 45 / 0.50);
}

.hero-button:hover {
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

/*************************
       NAVIGATION BAR
**************************/

.navbar {
    height: 12vh;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar img {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
}

.navbar-brand h2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: .2em;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 5px rgb(29 37 45 / 0.10);
}

#navbarToggle > ul > li {
    padding: .8em;
}

#navbarToggle > ul > li > a {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 5px rgb(29 37 45 / 20%);
}

#navbarToggle > .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid #f8f9fa;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.guided-tours-link a::before {
    content: "\f5eb";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.visit-us-link a::before {
    content: "\f4d7";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.about-us-link a::before {
    content: "\f1e5";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.bookings-link a::before {
    content: "\f07a";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.account-link a::before {
    content: "\f2bd";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media-queries/mq.css">
    <link href="/fontawesome-free-5.15.1-web/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--load all styles -->


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- google fonts -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
     <title>Explore Zion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="hero">
             <!-- navigation bar w/ bootstrap -->
             <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

                <!--  show this only on mobile to medium screens  -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="/img/icons/main-logo.svg" width="30" height="30" class="p-d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                    <h2>Explore Zion</h2>
                </a>

                  <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                
                <!--  use flexbox utility classes to change how the child elements are justified  -->
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between nav-link-container" id="navbarToggle">

                    <!--   show this only lg screens and up   -->
                    <span></span>
    
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-links-middle">
                      <li class="nav-item guided-tours-link">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Guided Tours In Zion</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item visit-us-link">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Visit Us</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item about-us-link">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-links-right">
                      <li class="nav-item bookings-link">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bookings
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item account-link">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            
            <!-- hero-content  -->
            <div class="hero-content">
                <h1 class="hero-title">
                    Zion Park <br/>Adventure Agency
                </h1>
                <p class="hero-desc">
                    Planning your first visit to Zion? Let us help to make your trip safe and astounding. We offer a broad and exciting range of walking tours in Zion for all skill levels.
                </p>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" class="hero-button">Private Guided Tours In Zion</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- introisection -->

      </div>


     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are we going to solve your problem if you don't put any reproducible code

Comment: Make a snippet and added a more code for solve your problem

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code, I had thought that the HTML was enough. I just updated it, and hopefully, there's enough info to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.navbar-collapse` element receives the class `show`, when it is expanded, which would help to add the appropriate styles. In your case, however, you need to style the `.navbar` element as well, so its class list has to be updated accordingly. This is where you can use the [Bootstrap collapse events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events), which will indicate when the menu is open.

```
<script>
    const navbar = $('nav.navbar');
    const navbarCollapse = $('.navbar-collapse');

    // Adding classes to indicate the navbar state
    navbarCollapse.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      navbar.addClass('expanded');
    });
    navbarCollapse.on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
      navbar.removeClass('expanded');
    });
</script>
```

Then, what's left is to set the required styles. Here is a simple demo in media query, but I think you can skip the media query itself. The collapse functionality is available only for smaller screens and this means the event handlers will set the `expanded` class to the nav only when you are on tablet and mobile. In other words, you wouldn't have expanded navbar on Desktop anyway.

```
/* The media query and the max-width are just for demo */
@media only screen and(max-width:1024px){
    .navbar.expanded {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .navbar.expanded .navbar-collapse {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .navbar.expanded .navbar-toggler-icon{
      color: black;
    }

    .navbar.expanded h2{
      color: black;
    }

    .navbar.expanded #navbarToggle>ul>li>a{
      color: black;
    }
}
```

From what I see in your code, the logo and the menu button are SVGs and you will probably have to switch the images, depending on the navbar state, or use the SVG code in the HTML, so that you can style them with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in debunking my code. It helped a lot!